# How can i tune this Mysql query for calulating Consumption for given time period?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

Actual the table contains the processed data of electrical meters which i have sampled from them on persecond basis after that data is processed on Hourly basis and inserted into `processed_data_hourly` table.

Now what i want to do is show the report as per the customer selected date and time period from `processed_data_hourly` table

Below query gives me the expected output which I want but it takes so much time to execute around 70 to 90 sec.

So can anyone help me to optimize this query so that the execution time will be less

```
Query :

    SELECT
        A.node_id,
        A.start_time,
        B.end_time,
        A.startReadingIMP,
        B.endReadingIMP,
        (B.endReadingIMP - A.startReadingIMP) diffIMP
    FROM
        ((SELECT
        node_id, start_time, end_time, srv_vah startReadingIMP
    FROM
        processed_data_hourly
    WHERE
        start_time >= '2017-05-15 00:00:00'
            AND end_time <= '2017-05-15 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY node_id
    ORDER BY start_time ASC) AS A, (SELECT
        node_id, start_time, end_time, erv_vah endReadingIMP
    FROM
        processed_data_hourly
    WHERE
        start_time >= '2017-05-15 00:00:00'
            AND end_time <= '2017-05-15 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY end_time DESC) AS B
   )
    WHERE
        A.node_id = 6 and B.node_id=6

    GROUP BY A.node_id , B.node_id
```

Expected output : 
[image: Output]

Table Structure

[image: Table Structure]

P.S: Table structure is too big to post as it contains lots of columns

Comment: If it does give you the result you want then that's lucky and you should read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html why this is so. It would help if you could edit the question to include the table definition as ,test data as text, an  explain of the query  and describe what you are trying to do

Comment: Lucky? It's a miracle.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this query?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have edited the question with more description

Comment: Do you have indexes over start_time & end_time?

Comment: @nacho sorry but NO i don't have indexes over start_time & end_time

Comment: @Hemant Sangle it would execute faster if you can make indexes over those columns, because most of your where clausules use start_time or end_time

Comment: @nacho for me its not feasible to add index on that column because my data insertion rate is very high

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is a syntax error in your query in this snippet:

```
    WHERE
        start_time >= '2017-05-15 00:00:00'
            AND end_time <= '2017-05-15 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY end_time DESC) AS B
   )
```

the `DESC` clause after `group by` list is not allowed.
I guess it should be `GROUP BY node_id ORDER BY end_time DESC` instead.

---

If my quess is correct, then my second remark is that your query uses [MySQL Group by extenstion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). According to the documentation:

> If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard
>   SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns
>   are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL
>   to accept the preceding query. In this case, **the server is free to
>   choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the
>   values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.** Result set sorting occurs
>   after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which
>   value within each group the server chooses. Disabling
>   ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some
>   property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not
>   named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

---

One may say that actually your query is picking random rows from the table.
You can observe that in this simple demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8faefc/1)

```
SELECT * FROM processed_data_hourly;

| node_id |           start_time |             end_time | srv_vah | erv_vah |
|---------|----------------------|----------------------|---------|---------|
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:01:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:14:00Z |      11 |     111 |
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:05:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:12:00Z |      22 |     222 |
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:04:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:13:00Z |      33 |     333 |
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:07:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:10:00Z |      44 |     444 |
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:08:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:21:00Z |      55 |     555 |
```

---

```
SELECT
        A.node_id,
        A.start_time,
        B.end_time,
        A.startReadingIMP,
        B.endReadingIMP,
        (B.endReadingIMP - A.startReadingIMP) diffIMP
    FROM
        ((SELECT
        node_id, start_time, end_time, srv_vah startReadingIMP
    FROM
        processed_data_hourly
    WHERE
        start_time >= '2017-05-15 00:00:00'
            AND end_time <= '2017-05-15 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY node_id
    ORDER BY start_time ASC) AS A, (SELECT
        node_id, start_time, end_time, erv_vah endReadingIMP
    FROM
        processed_data_hourly
    WHERE
        start_time >= '2017-05-15 00:00:00'
            AND end_time <= '2017-05-15 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY node_id
    ORDER BY end_time DESC) AS B
   )
    WHERE
        A.node_id = 6 and B.node_id=6
    GROUP BY A.node_id , B.node_id

| node_id |           start_time |             end_time | startReadingIMP | endReadingIMP | diffIMP |
|---------|----------------------|----------------------|-----------------|---------------|---------|
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:01:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:14:00Z |              11 |           111 |     100 |
```

---

If you analyze the above result, you can see that boths subqueries picked the first row, that is:

```
| node_id |           start_time |             end_time | srv_vah | erv_vah |
|---------|----------------------|----------------------|---------|---------|
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:01:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:14:00Z |      11 |     111 |
```

---

If this is really a result you want, you can rewrite your query into another one that orders the table by `id,  start_time` and pick only the first row for each `id`, something like:

```
SELECT node_id,
       start_time,
       end_time,
       srv_vah As startReadingIMP,
       erv_vah As endReadingIMP,
       erv_vah - srv_vah As diffIMP 
FROM processed_data_hourly a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM processed_data_hourly b
  WHERE a.node_id = b.node_id
    AND b.start_time < a.start_time
);

| node_id |           start_time |             end_time | startReadingIMP | endReadingIMP | diffIMP |
|---------|----------------------|----------------------|-----------------|---------------|---------|
|       6 | 2017-05-15T00:01:00Z | 2017-05-15T00:14:00Z |              11 |           111 |     100 |
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8faefc/5

---

Next, if you add an index on `node_id, start_time`, then this query should be really fast.